# How pass StatusBarNotification to Activity

Tags: android

I have less experience with Notification Listener Service. Trying to pass StatusBarNotification as a parameter via intent on Android 4.4. I don't know it is possible or not.

**Here is Notification Listener Service:**

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

            intent = new Intent("INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION");
            intent.putExtra("sbn", sbn); //don't know possible or not
            sendBroadcast(intent);  

    }
}
```

**Here is Activity Receiver:**

```
private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {

            //How get StatusBarNotification here????????
        }

    }
}
```

**I also tried to pass data:**

```
intent = new Intent("INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION");
intent.putExtra("sbn",sbn.getPackageName()); 
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And no problem with it.

But need to pass 'StatusBarNotification'.
If not possible to pass 'StatusBarNotification' via intent then please let me know if any other way to doing this...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Parcelable or creat own parcelable class object if required here is example.

```
private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        StatusBarNotification myNotification = (StatusBarNotification)intent.getParcelableExtra("sbn");
        if(myNotification != null) {
            //StatusBarNotification successfully retrieved
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`StatusBarNotification` does implement `Parcelable` interface so it should be prone to `Intent` transfer, though I've never tried it personally.
Use this to retrieve it in the receiver:

```
private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            StatusBarNotification myNotification = (StatusBarNotification)intent.getParcelableExtra("sbn");
            if(myNotification != null) {
                //StatusBarNotification successfully retrieved
            }
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.html)'s a link to Google's documentation for further research.